# Views: Filter by whether a node is <front>?

Tags: views

Is there a way to filter a view by whether the item is set to <front>? Seems simple but it's not as easy as I'd have guessed.

Comment: What do you mean by *<front>*? The sites frontpage or content marked as *published on front*?

Comment: I've never used it, but the [Variable](https://drupal.org/project/variable) module has Views integration - maybe you could use that to filter against the front page variable `site_frontpage` and a concatenation of `node/` and the node id field?

Comment: if this is in a block, you could use the Block UI to restrict it to display on just `<front>` and that should do it.  if it is a page, you could use a contextual filter that isn't given an argument via the path and then use php to provide the argument's value and do anything you want in there.

Comment: Node: Front Page Filter by whether or not the node has been promoted to Front Page. https://drupal.org/node/54457

Comment: @Michiel and Bala I don't mean content that is promoted to front page. I mean to filter by whether it is set as the site's frontpage in the site information settings. Jimajamma, I don't want to only show the view on the frontpage, I want it to filter content by whether that content is set to front page.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve above problem using [Views PHP](https://drupal.org/project/views_php) module.

> This module allows the admin account (user 1) to add fields, filters
>   and sorts to views which use PHP code. It also supports additional
>   accounts when the core PHP Filter module is enabled.

All you need to do is create a filter Global PHP and below code in the php filter. **It's highly recommended that you include this within a module rather than directly in views. If it breaks it could be difficult to recover from.**

```
function yourmodule_exclude_front($data) {
  if (!empty($data)) {
    $front_url = variable_get('site_frontpage');
    $url_parts = explode("/", $front_url);
    if (($url_parts[0] == 'node') && ($url_parts[1] == $data->nid)) {
     return TRUE; //Exclude the node
    }
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

Then within your view php filter you would do something like:

```
 if (module_exists('yourmodule')) {
   return yourmodule_exclude_front($data);
 }
```

Exported view code below (not including module code from above, but inline code)

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'front_view_node';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Front View Node';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Front View Node';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'node';
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Global: PHP */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['php']['id'] = 'php';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['php']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['php']['field'] = 'php';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['php']['use_php_setup'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['php']['php_filter'] = '$front_url = variable_get(\'site_frontpage\');
$url_parts = explode("/", $front_url);
if ($url_parts[0] == \'node\' && $url_parts[1] == $data->nid) {
  return FALSE;
}
else {
  return TRUE;
}';

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'front-view-node';
```

Comment: If I were going to write custom PHP for this I would create it as a custom filter handler in a module, not to store PHP in the database with Views.